# Is there a way to sort a list by a binary comparator in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to sort a `List<Pair<Int, Int>>` according to their ratio with a lambda binary comparator to avoid precision errors, but so far I only know the `sortBy` or `sortWith` function which only takes one single object for sorting. In c++ I would write:

```cpp
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::pair<int, int> a, std::pair<int, int> b) {
    return a.first * b.second < a.second * b.first;
}
```

Is there equivalent kotlin code for that? Thanks.

Comment: Your C++ code is sorting a collection of pairs. If you have a collection of pairs in Kotlin, then you can do the same thing. However, with the current state of the question, it's hard to know the type of the collection and the values inside it, so it's hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sortedWith` function actually takes a `Comparator`, so you can pass a lambda (thanks to SAM conversion) and you can actually deal with 2 objects:

```kotlin
list.sortedWith { a, b -> a.first * b.second - a.second * b.first }
```

The difference with your function is that this must return an integer (-1, 0, 1) depending on the order, not just a boolean. Check out the [`Comparator` contract](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/compare.html)

Comment: Why can I pass in a lambda directly?

Comment: In Kotlin, if the last argument to a function is a lambda, it can be passed outside the parentheses as syntax sugar. See [passing trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas).

Comment: But the [sortedWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) function takes a Comparator as its last argument. I wonder if the lambda is used to initialise the Comparator object directly?

Comment: The lambda is used as a `Comparator`, you can pass it as is written here. This is called SAM conversion, you can look it up ;)

Comment: Oh thanks. Or I would have no clue how to look that up.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close:

```kotlin
    pairList.sortedWith { a, b ->        
        when (a.first * b.second < a.second * b.first) {
            true -> ...
            false -> ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the `when` block?  What goes in there?

Comment: The lambda implements [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/compare.html) and should return the specified value in that contract.

Comment: The lambda is expected to return a value in `{-1, 0, 1}` to satisfy the `Comparator` API. The `when` expression is where the `x` value can be converted as needed